# Docker stopped container restarted automatically

Tags: java, docker, chef-infra

I had a docker container which was running and which was created using below chef command(**Update**)

```
docker_container node['docker']['image'] do
  repo node['docker']['repo']
  port '80:8080'
  log_opts ['max-size=1m', 'max-file=1']
  command 'env'
  tag node['docker']['tag']
  sensitive true
  action :run
end
```

Container was stopped with the help of below command.

```
docker stop docker-container-name
```

On checking current status it was down for below command

```
docker ps -a
Exited 2 minutes ago
```

But after around an hour it restarted automatically, what may be the reason, please help me to understand this.

```
 docker ps -a
```

Shows currenlty same stopped container is running

Comment: How you start this docker ? Maybe a `restart:always` parameters is defined

Comment: It seems like @MathieuLescaudron is right, according to the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/ this behaviour occurs when --restart is used on the container startup.

Comment: Please check the update thanks for your replies

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Chef in daemon mode or as a cron job or just running it manually for other reasons, it would get restarted. You told Chef to make sure that container is running (`action :run`), so it does.

Comment: Wouldn't this start up a new container? Or would it start the currently stopped container? However, if the chef docker block WOULD make the stopped containers start, then i think you are correct.

Comment: You would have to dig through the internals of the custom resource to see how it tracks state, but the overall effect is that it is doing what you asked.